# Followed user's feeds in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, chatter

Can anyone tell me how to get the organization Chatter id?
My usecase is:
I wanna get the chatter feeds of user that I followed. So that I can add comments,likes for that feed..
For this I have created a visualforce page:

public class VFC06_ChatterFollow{

```
public list<User> userList {get;set;}

public VFC06_ChatterFollow(){
    userList = [select id, lastname, firstname, profile.Name, profile.Usertype from user
                    where isactive = true
                    and profile.Usertype = 'Standard'
                    and id != :UserInfo.getUserId()];

}
```

}

Thanks in advance
Karthick

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean to ask how you get the id of Chatter users (not the org) that you are following. You can do so with the following approach

```
// Everyone you're following
EntitySubscription[] followingES = [select id, parentid, subscriberid, parent.name 
                                    from EntitySubscription
                                    where subscriberid =:uid];//Set to the User's Id

List<EntitySubscription> following = new List<EntitySubscription> ();
String userSObjectPrefix =  User.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
for( EntitySubscription es: followingES )
{
      if( ('' + es.parentid).substring(0,3) == 
                        userSObjectPrefix) // users only
      {
             following.add(es);
      }       
}
Integer followingUserCount = following.size();
```

Comment: I wanna feeds of user That I followed on Visualforce Page

Comment: For That how Can I create visualforce Page

Answer (score 0):

Use the classes/methods in the Apex ConnectApi namespace: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_connect_api.htm

For info about which methods to call to get feeds, scroll down to "Getting feed elements from a feed" on this page: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_feeds_feed_elements.htm